# Using Regex in Pandas to change case of captured string

Tags: python, pandas, regex, string, replace

I'm trying to capitalize the first letter after a parantheses in a dataframe column.

This is the closest I got but I don't know how to actually reference the string that is captured so I can apply `.upper()` method to it

```
df['item_name'] = df['item_name'].str.replace(r"(?<=[(])[a-z]", ###what to put?###.upper(), regex=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ca pass a function as replacement value:

```
df['item_name'] = df['item_name'].str.replace(r"(?<=[(])[a-z]",
                                              lambda m: m.group().upper(),
                                              regex=True)
```

Example: vowels to uppercase.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['abcde', 'fghij']})
df['B'] = df['A'].str.replace(r"[aeiou]", lambda m: m.group().upper(), regex=True)
```

output:

```
       A      B
0  abcde  AbcdE
1  fghij  fghIj
```